# ArcPy Error - 'continue' not properly in loop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

[image]Is there a way to get the continue function to work? Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: This thread indicates that there may be a [mix of spaces and tabs][1].  If you are getting error messages, then indicating them would be useful.  It may be appropriate to delete continue all together.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799974/continue-on-except-of-a-try-block-in-python

Comment: This seems to be a pure Python rather than ArcPy question so is probably better researched/asked at Stack Overflow. In any event if you are posting ArcPy questions here can you always post the code as text (use the **`{}`** button to format it) rather than a picture because that way it is much easier for people to copy/paste from for code testing.

Comment: My error says this: There's an error in your program: ***'continue' not properly in loop (ExtractByMask,py, line 23).                   I have tried re-writing my script so that there are no indentation errors but I still get the same error every time. I also tried the pass function to no avail. Is there somewhere else I should be putting the continue function?

Comment: Thank you alpha-beta-soup!! That was exactly what was wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's likely you have a mix of tabs and spaces. Rather, your continue statement is exactly as the error states: not properly in the loop.

```
# SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
try:
    for i in range(0,10):
        print i
        if i == 7:
            raise Exception
except:
    print("Except %d" % i)
    continue # Error
```

You don't need your continue statement at all; you can just remove it from the above code and it will work. But it seems to me from reading your code over your shoulder as it were, that you probably want your `try` and `except` inside the `for` loop.

```
for i in range(0,10):
    try:
        print i
        if i == 7:
            raise Exception
    except:
        print("Except %d" % i)
```